# Unable to setup Network on VMware/ VirtualBox

Tags: windows, redhat-enterprise-linux, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

Host system is windows 8.1.

So i install Redhat Linux 5.11 on VMware and VirtualBox. And assign bridged network connection but it is not able to ping the gateway. So in VMware 11.0 Virtual Network Editor i saw that in Bridged Network it is connecting to Bluetooth device and it is not showing any other interface wireless or ethernet.

[image]

By doing google i came to know that this windows 8.1 have networking issues. But couldn't any good solution.

Question is why other interfaces are not showing ....

Comment: VMWare AND VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes tried both. Both not working ......

Comment: At a guess, I would try networking in the physical card, not any virtual networks.